# Postgresql and devise db migrate failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, devise, rake

Can't get rake to migrate db with postgresql when using devise gem.

```
rake db:migrate --trace
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
** Invoke db:_dump (first_time)
** Execute db:_dump
** Invoke db:schema:dump (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Invoke db:load_config 
** Execute db:schema:dump
```

`rake db:migrate:status` returns nothing:

```
database: sampleapp_development

 Status   Migration ID    Migration Name
--------------------------------------------------
```

If I do `rails g scaffold <WHATEVER> name email` and I run rake db:migrate it all works well, but with devise...nothing.

gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.1'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'bootstrap-generators', '~> 3.1.1'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.1.1'

gem 'simple_form'

gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production

gem 'devise'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring',     group: :development

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

Comment: Are you able to see devise migration file generated?

Comment: @nidhi yes i am. I can see all the migration files `20140621182346_devise_create_users`

Comment: That's weird.. By any chance can you try to drop database and run all migrations again

Comment: I did that already. I don't know why this isn't working either.. about to just go back to mysql

Comment: Database should not make a difference. Let me try it once on my machine. .. Will post comment in few minutes

Comment: Paste result of `select * from schema_migrations;` run in `rails db`

Comment: @f1f5 Hey I just tried locally with sample application using PostgreSQL database and was able to create table using migration.

Comment: Followed below steps

- rails generate devise:install
- rails generate devise User

Comment: Can you post your migration file here?

Comment: @MichalSzyndel I still can't run `rails db` I have navicat and pgadmin all able to connect fine. I get this error and dont know why I get it or how to fix it: `dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/psql
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5`

Comment: @NidhiSarvaiya just the standard devise migration file. (untouched)

Comment: navicat show the development db. I can connect to it. It only has an empty `schema_migrations` file. Nothing else in it. I deleted the db and ran `rake db:create:all` my development and test db was again created but still migration from devise is not showing and it is not creating the `users` table

Comment: UPDATE -- got `rails db` to work. Had to uninstall and reinstall: `brew install readline`

Comment: Hey can you check your migration file name once.. somebody had posted similar issue here https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4496102

Comment: Yeah you need to add `.rb` to the end of your migration file name. Then it should work. This issue seems to come up every once in a while with Devise.

Comment: @NidhiSarvaiya I f**king love you. I can't believe this!! Been going nuts for hours. It was a freaking .txt file instead of a .rb file. Using rubymine as a new editor and I just thought the syntax was gray because the migration hadn't run yet. It didn't realize the file extension. What a nightmare. All resolved now. Thanks!

Comment: @NidhiSarvaiya post an official answer so that I can accept it and close out the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please check the migration file generated by Devise. As sometimes it generates a file with txt extension which will not run your migrations.

Need to rename the file with rb extension to work it correctly.